# UninitializedPropertyAccessException when testing a Spring Boot service with Mock objects

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, mockito, jparepository

I'm encountering an issue when trying to write JUnit tests for a Spring Boot service using Mockito for mocking dependencies. Specifically, I'm getting an UninitializedPropertyAccessException when trying to use a lateinit property in my test class.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// UserService.kt

@Service
class UserService() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    fun createNewUser(userId: String, email: String, username: String) : UserEntity{
        validateUserDoesNotExists(userId = userId, email = email, username = username)
        val newUserEntity = UserEntity(userId = userId, email = email, username = username)
        userRepository.save(newUserEntity)
        userRepository.flush()
        return newUserEntity
    }

    private fun validateUserDoesNotExists(userId: String, email: String, username: String){
        if(userRepository.findByUserId(userId) != null){
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "User already exists")
        }
        if(userRepository.findByEmail(email) != null){
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "Email already registered")
        }
        if (userRepository.findByUsername(username) != null){
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "Username already taken")
        }
    }
}
```

```
// UserServiceTest.kt

class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun testCreateNewUser_Success() {
        Mockito.`when`(userRepository.save(any(UserEntity::class.java))).thenReturn(testUser)

        val createdUser: UserEntity = userService.createNewUser(
            userId = "123456789",
            email = "asdf@xyz.com",
            username = "test"
        )

        assert(createdUser.userId == "123456789")
        assert(createdUser.email == "asdf@xyz.com")
        assert(createdUser.username == "test")
    }

}
```

When I run my tests, I receive the following error:

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property userRepository has not been initialized`

I've tried using MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) in the @BeforeEach method as suggested in some online resources, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Could someone please help me understand why I'm encountering this error and provide guidance on how to properly initialize userRepository in my test class? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.